# Presenting a table in wpf application

Tags: wpf-controls

I need to present a table in my wpf application . Which control could i use to do it?
Thanks.

Comment: What kind of table? Does it have several columns? Is it editable? What do you want the users to do with it?

Comment: Please tell us more about this mythical table.

Answer (score 0):

Use datagrid or you could use a listview.